# PHP sort subgroup only of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

not sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find in the other answers a way to sort a multidimensional array subgroups, without touching the main order.

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apples
            [type] => 1
            [sales] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apples
            [type] => 2
            [sales] => 30
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apples
            [type] => 3
            [sales] => 20
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oranges
            [type] => 1
            [sales] => 30
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oranges
            [type] => 2
            [sales] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oranges
            [type] => 3
            [sales] => 20
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lemons
            [type] => 1
            [sales] => 10
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lemons
            [type] => 2
            [sales] => 30
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lemons
            [type] => 3
            [sales] => 20
        )
)
```

What I need to do is sorting each 'name' group (Apples, Oranges and Lemons) by the key 'sales', leaving the order of keys 'name' Apples, Oranges and Lemons unaltered, so result should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apples
            [type] => 1
            [sales] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apples
            [type] => 3
            [sales] => 20
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apples
            [type] => 2
            [sales] => 30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oranges
            [type] => 2
            [sales] => 10

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oranges
            [type] => 3
            [sales] => 20
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oranges
            [type] => 1
            [sales] => 30
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lemons
            [type] => 1
            [sales] => 10
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lemons
            [type] => 3
            [sales] => 20
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lemons
            [type] => 2
            [sales] => 30
        )
)
```

I can't find any way to do this, anyone can give me a hint about this?

Thanks!

Comment: `usort`, `usort`, `usort`

Comment: @gege first of all arrange your array in php form and show what you have tried?

Comment: The array structure is unclear from the "code" you posted. Please post a valid php arrray definition.

Comment: Sorry everyone I edited the question with proper PHP array to make its structure more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gege try this:

```
<?php
    $arr =  array(
                array(
                        "name" => "Apples",
                        "type" => 1,
                        "sales" => 10
                    ),
                 array(
                        "name" => "Apples",
                        "type" => 2,
                        "sales" => 30
                    ),
                 array(
                        "name" => "Apples",
                        "type" => 3,
                        "sales" => 20
                    ),
                array(
                        "name" => "Oranges",
                        "type" => 1,
                        "sales" => 30
                    ),
                array(
                        "name" => "Oranges",
                        "type" => 2,
                        "sales" => 10
                    ),
                array(
                        "name" => "Oranges",
                        "type" => 3,
                        "sales" => 20
                    ),
                array(
                        "name" => "Lemons",
                        "type" => 1,
                        "sales" => 10
                    ),
               array(
                        "name" => "Lemons",
                        "type" => 2,
                        "sales" => 30
                    ),
                array(
                        "name" => "Lemons",
                        "type" => 3,
                        "sales" => 20
                    )
            );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr); // array before

    function sortArr($a, $b){
        if($a["name"] == $b["name"]){
            if($a["sales"] == $b["sales"]){
                return 0;
            }
            return($a["sales"] < $b["sales"] ? -1 : 1);
        }
        else{
            return($a["name"] < $b["name"] ? -1 : 1);
        }
    }

    usort($arr, "sortArr");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr); // array after
```

Comment: Thank you this works! I have to understand now how it does it, somehow the PHP way of sorting arrays seems very confusing to me and I didn't think about using it on two levels as you did. Brilliant, time to study now and understand it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of readability, I reduced your array (it should still work for yours though).

```
<?php
// The array structured as assumed according to your example
$groceries = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Apples",
        "type" => 1,
        "sales" => 10
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Apples",
        "type" => 2,
        "sales" => 30
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Apples",
        "type" => 3,
        "sales" => 20
    ),
);


/**
 * See the PHP docs for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
 */
$sortBySales = function ($a, $b){
    return $a['sales'] - $b['sales'];
};


echo "<h1>Unsorted</h1>";
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($groceries);
echo "</pre>";

usort($groceries, $sortBySales);

echo "<h1>Sorted</h1>";
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($groceries);
echo "</pre>";
```

---

**EDIT**

I forgot that the array should have the names grouped as well. Now, *@BunkerBoy* alread posted the solution, but for the sake of completness, here is the updated sorting function:

```
$sortBySales = function ($a, $b){
    if($a["name"] == $b["name"]){
        return $a['sales'] - $b['sales'];
    }else{
        return($a["name"] < $b["name"] ? -1 : 1);
    }
};
```

**Note** that the only difference to *@BunkerBoy*'s function is that I reduced the comparison to a calculation.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work as my main need is to keep the subkey "Name" grouped. Expanding the array as in my example and using your code result is not what I need as it alters the order of 'Apples' and 'Oranges' mixing them. I need all 'Apples' and all 'Oranges' to be one after the other in their original order (all Apples, then all Oranges, then all Lemons), but sort each of these groups by Sales, so first all Apples by sales, then all Oranges, then all Lemons (try applying your code to my original array and you'll see is different from the result I need).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot about that - but it seems @BunkerBoy already solved the issue :-)

Comment: Thank you, your variation will help understanding the process as it produces same result in a slightly different way! :)